# get meta data of mp3 with getID3 PHP

Tags: php, mp3, getid3

I'm trying to get the meta data out from my mp3 playlist using PHP and the library getid3, I'm sure the file path is correct and the mp3 has some information on meta data, but the information returns me null.
Here is my code :

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json");

require_once('getid3/getid3.php');

$input = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
$action = $input['action'];

switch ($action) 
{   
    case "get_songs":

    $currentDirectory = dirname(dirname(getcwd()));
    $directory = $currentDirectory."/resources/assets/playlists/";

    $files = glob($directory."*.mp3");

    for($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++)
    {
        $getID3 = new getID3;
        $file = ($files[$i]);
        $ThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($file);
        $Result = array('song_url'=>($files[$i]), "tags"=> $ThisFileInfo);
        $data[] = $Result;
    }

    $result = array("result"=>"ok","data"=>$data);  

    break;
}

echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

I know the library is working, because when I force it to access a local file it returns me :

```
"GETID3_VERSION" = "1.7.4";
                error =                 (
                    "Could not open file \"AYO.mp3\""
                );
```

Could it be, I cant access files from another path?

Comment: have you checked the permission for the file?

Comment: @AngularDev sure, its 644, but already tried with 777 and not worked too.

Comment: hardcode the filepath and make sure the mp3 exists on the server is not corrupted while uploading or something

Because i personally love the getid3 it never give such problems.

Comment: Checked that too, using file_exists(), returns me "1" to all files.

Comment: did you tried playing the track? because everything is proper as per the code you have posted

Comment: Just tried that, and plays correctly in the browser.

Comment: I guess getid3 have some demo scripts where you can browse your mp3 directory and just select mp3 and it will show up the Tag Info. It was way back don't know if they have it now also or not.